# How do you find the area of the region bounded by the polar curve $r=3+2\sin 2\theta$

Tags: integration, area, polar-coordinates

I keep getting my answer as 11pi, my method I think seems right. Could someone please helep

Comment: We can't tell if your method is valid if you don't show your work...

Comment: I use the double integral 2pi-0 and then 3+2sin(Thea) lower bound zero r dr theta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$A=\frac {1}{2}\int r(\theta)^2d\theta$$

Comment: I did exactly that my limits were 2pi and 0

Comment: that doesn't help I did exactly that, and got 11 pi is it the limits which I used were wrong

Comment: I get $11\pi$ too. What should the answer be?